# Variant vagrant using wordmove to deploy and utf8mb4 problems

Tags: mysql, wordpress, vagrant, utf8mb4

I try to use variant vagrant and wordmove to deploy my work.

[VVV](https://github.com/Varying-Vagrant-Vagrants/VVV)

Several attempts later, I understand I have a difference of mysql version between VVV - mysql 5.5 and my distant server - mysql 5.1.
The problem is [utf8mb4](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)
When wordmove dump local database, they create utf8mb4 and of course my mysql distant on 5.1 break the dump.

Someone have this trouble or have an idea how resolve this?

Thanks for reading my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

MySql 5.1 is past end of life, meaning that unless you subscribe to paid support from Oracle, no updates will be available for you. You need to upgrade to the same version that's on the vagrant box.

If you are unable to do so, you should downgrade the MySql version on the vagrant box. Your dev environment should exactly match your production environment - otherwise you will not be able to completely test code and deploy with the confidence that your software works.

You can also change the table encoding on the local MySql server to UTF8, but know that this does not support 4 byte UTF8 characters, so your Wordpress blog won't support emoticons and some other special characters. Note that I consider this a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Until we're having troubles aligning development with hosting environments, we're using a dirty trick, dropping this little hook inside `wp-content/mu-plugins/mysql-colation-fixer.php`

https://gist.github.com/pioneerskies/8a3dc7da62017b87e9aa

Note the comment at the very last line and note **this is intended to be a provisory wrokaround**